# Getting error while passing list for member to zremAsync?

Tags: node.js, redis

I have an issue while using the `zremAsync` while using redis with nodejs. Below is my example.

````
```Redis.client.zremAsync(test:user:123, [1,2,3]).then(c=>{
      console.log(c)
 })```
````

If I'm trying like this getting this error **warning: REDIS: Deprecated: The ZREM command contains a argument of type Array.**
**"This is converted to "1,2,3" by using .toString() now and will return an error from v.3.0 on.
"**

Can someone please help.

Comment: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/issues/1233

Comment: It won't solve my problem. I already checked it. In my case I want to delete key.

Comment: If you found the solution, could you post it?